# Get the middle character in string

Tags: regex

I make a HTTP POST to a third-party API 
and it returned

`USR-19-1576931418453`

And I need the middle of the string which is 19

The pattern basically 
 `type-id-random_number_by_third_party_api`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your string only has three hyphen-separated terms, and your regex engine support lookarounds, you may use:

```
(?<=-)[^-]+(?=-)
```

### Demo

Practically speaking, if you are using a programming language, I would suggest just splitting the input string on `-`, and then retaining whatever component you want (in this case, the second component).

Comment: thanks mate
yeah you right i think ill split the input
but im curious how can i do it with regex